# relationship between density of edges to the number of vertices in graph

Tags: graph-algorithm

I want to understand how to compute big-O for a dense versus sparse graph.
"Algorithms in a nutshell" says that for sparse graph, O(E) is O(V) and for dense graph O(E) is closer to O(V^2). Does anyone know how is that derived?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not derived, it's a definition. In a fully connected (directed) graph with self-loops, the number of edges |*E*| = |*V*|² so the definition of a dense graph is reasonable. The definition of a sparse graph is one where O(|*E*|) = O(|*V*|), so there's a constant maximum number of edges per vertex.

Note that if the number of edges is much smaller, e.g. O(lg |*V*|), then it's still O(|*V*|) as well. One could imagine a "semi-sparse" class of graphs with |*E*| = O(|*V*| lg |*V*|) or something like that, but I personally have never encountered such a class in practice.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the self-loops! Makes sense now:)

Comment: @iralight: thanks for accepting, but the self-loops aren't the issue. Even in a complete undirected graph without self-loops, the number of edges is |V|×(|V|-1)/2 which is O(|V|²).

Comment: Understood...just conceptually it made sense to me that with self-loops I was able to populate a V^2 adjacency matrix completely. Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the graph is [simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29#Simple_graph) - at the worst case every node can be connected to all `|V|-1` other nodes, resulting in [in not directed graph:] `|E| = (|V|-1) + (|V| -2)  + ... + 1 <= |V| * (|V| -1) =  O(|V|^2)`. And in directed graph: `|E| = |V| * (|V|-1) = O(|V|^2)`.

A good example for a dense graph is a [clique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_%28graph_theory%29)  - which have all the edges.

For sparsed graph - we assume the number of edges connected to each vertex is bounded by a constant. Let this constant be `k`. Thus: `|E| <= k* |V|`, and we get `|E| = O(|V|)`

A good example for a sparsed graph is the internet, where every URL is a node and every link is an edge.

Note that if the graph is not simple, you cannot bound `|E|` with any function of `|V|`.

Comment: I'm having problem understanding the formula for the dense graph:  |E| = (|V|-1) + (|V| -2) + ... + 1 <= |V| * (|V| -1) = O(|V|^2). Is this based on some mathematical formula that simplifies sum of (x-i) to x^2?

Comment: @iralight: yes, it is [sum of arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum). Have a look at the attached link.